# Webpack resolve alias doesn't work

Tags: webpack

I have a pretty tangled project structure, so I decided to use webpack's `resolve.alias`. Resolve looks like this in my config:

```
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      scss: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source', 'sass') // I tried '..', 'source' as well
    }
  },
...
```

But when I use it in my js

```
import utils from 'scss/_utilities';
```

I am getting an `Cannot find module` error.

My directory structure is like this:

```
| webpack
|- dev.js
|- prod.js
| source
|- sass
|-- _common.scss
|-- _variables.scss
|-- globals.scss
|- js
|-- components
|--- Card
|---- index.js // from here I am importing
```

I am using Webpack 3.

I tried various notations with and without tilde (`~`), with and without extension (`.scss`), with or without underscore prefix (`_`). What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your alias seems to be set almost correctly. You've to use `'..'` as well, so it looks like this.

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      scss: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'source', 'sass')
    }
  },
```

Yet the main problem lies in your import statement. Since you're trying to import some SCSS you can not use `import utils from 'scss/_utilities';`. Instead you have to use `@import '~scss/_utilities.scss';` (NOTE: do not forget to use the tilde (`~`).

Comment: I tried using `scss: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'source', 'sass')` with no avail. I also tried to import scss files from other scss files with `@import `@import '~scss/_utilities.scss';` (with other combinations with or without ~, _ and .scss), it also doesn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify. Where does your webpack configuration lie? In `yourProject/webpack/dev.js`?

Comment: Yes, and I run webpack with npm script: `"webpack --config ./webpack/prod.js -p"`

Comment: Well, for me this setup is working fine on Webpack 3.5.5. You may try to update Webpack or even downgrade it to an earlier version, since this seems to be a known problem as you can see here. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4160